# Student Schedule Assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's wrong with my code (this uses Python)?:

```
print("*************************************************")
first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
last_name = input("What is your last name? ")
student_id = int(input("Student ID: "))
print("*                                               *")
print("*    " + last_name + ", " + first_name + "       ID: " + str(student_id) + " *")
print("*                                               *")
print("*************************************************")
print("*                                               *")

periods = " "
block = 0
while periods != "STOP":
    periods = str(input("Enter the next class, STOP to end: "))
    room_number = int(input("Enter the room number: "))
    block += 1
    print("*       Block " + str(block) + ": " + periods + "\tRoom: " + str(room_number) + "\t*")

print("*                                               *")
print("*************************************************")
print("*                                               *")
print("*************************************************")
```

After entering 6 classes and when I type in "STOP" for 'periods', it doesn't stop immediately and asks for a room number again? How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop checks the condition at the beginning of each iteration. You change the condition partway through the loop, so it runs the rest of whatever is in the loop. If you use the following code, `periods` will be "STOP" before the loop runs again:

```
...
periods = " "
block = 0
periods = str(input("Enter the next class, STOP to end: "))
while periods != "STOP":
    room_number = int(input("Enter the room number: "))
    block += 1
    print("*       Block " + str(block) + ": " + periods + "\tRoom: " + str(room_number) + "\t*")
    periods = str(input("Enter the next class, STOP to end: "))
...
```

If this solved your problem then make sure to click the check to tell stack overflow that it did the trick!

Recommendation: On the line below you should use `format()` like this:

```
print("*    {0}, {1}       ID: {2} *".format(last_name,first_name,str(student_id)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.8 you can use an assignment expression in the `while` condition:

```
while (periods := input("Enter the next class, STOP to end: ")) != "STOP":
    room_number = int(input("Enter the room number: "))
    ...
```